# DatagridView dual language headers

Tags: asp.net

I need to support 2 languages in my website.
Which is the right way to set the correct language on each column header?
I don't want to use the column index to access it. I want to loop on all the columns and for each one get the right text for it, by it's name or other key from the cache.

Using framework 4.0, asp.net, c#.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I meant something more like this:

```
        if (ctl is GridView)
        {
            GridView oGrid = (GridView)ctl;
            foreach (DataControlField oClm in oGrid.Columns)
            {
                string str = string.Empty;

                str = frm.Page.ToString().Replace("ASP.", "").Replace("_aspx", "") + "_" + ctl.ID.ToString() + "_" + oClm.HeaderText.Replace(" ", "");
                Dr = DsGuiText.Tables[0].Select("Language = '" + sLang + "' And Key = '" + str + "'");
                if (Dr.Length > 0)
                {
                    oClm.HeaderText = Dr[0]["Value"].ToString();
                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you will need to reverse look up the localized header text when you loop through the column header.

[Here's a way to reverse look up localized string.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563506/reverse-a-resourcemanager)